# How to sort list in a custom order in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, sorting

I want to sort a list on custom order based on enum class.

```
enum class{
 TYPE1,
 TYPE2,
 TYPE3
}
```

Sorted list should be like that
Items with Type1 at top, then Type2 and then type3.

Please help me sort list in this situation.

Comment: [`sortedBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-by.html) / [`sortBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sort-by.html) / [`sort`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sort.html) / [`sortedWith`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-with.html) / [`sortWith`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sort-with.html) (see [`kotlin.collections`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/) for more options)

Comment: You don't have even remotely enough for anyone to help you. You could also define an enum set where each enum is the sort function: `enum class Foo : Comparable<T>` Then you can do `listOf(thing,thing2,thing3).sortWith(Foo.TYPE1)`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have some item with a `type` property, one simple way is to just inline an exhaustive `when` statement within a `sortedBy` block:

```kotlin
class MyItem(val type: Type)

enum class Type { TYPE1, TYPE2, TYPE3 }
```

```kotlin
val sortedlist = 
  myItemList.sortedBy { item ->
    when (item.type) {
      Type.TYPE1 -> 0
      Type.TYPE2 -> 1
      Type.TYPE3 -> 2
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

If your enum class has no attributes, then you need to sort by the enum ordinal, which is the order you define your enum class.

```
fun main() {
  val items = listOf(
    Item(name = "item1", type = Type.TYPE1),
    Item(name = "item2", type = Type.TYPE2),
    Item(name = "item3", type = Type.TYPE3),
    Item(name = "item4", type = Type.TYPE1),
    Item(name = "item5", type = Type.TYPE2),
    Item(name = "item6", type = Type.TYPE3),
  )
    items.sortedBy { it.type }.forEach { println("${it.name}") }
    // item1, item4, item2, item5, item3, item6
}

enum class Type() {
    TYPE1,
    TYPE2,
    TYPE3
}

class Item(val name: String, val type: Type) {}
```

However, you can define the Type enum class with some attributes, like priority in your case, then you can sort items by this attribute, and the order is not longer related to the order of enum cases.

```
fun main() {
    val items = listOf(
        Item(name = "item1", type = Type.TYPE1),
        Item(name = "item2", type = Type.TYPE2),
        Item(name = "item3", type = Type.TYPE3),
        Item(name = "item4", type = Type.TYPE1),
        Item(name = "item5", type = Type.TYPE2),
        Item(name = "item6", type = Type.TYPE3),
    )
    items.sortedBy { it.type.priority }.forEach { println("${it.name}")}
// item3, item6, item1, item4, item2, item5
}
enum class Type(val priority: Int) {
    TYPE1(1),
    TYPE2(2),
    TYPE3(0)
}

class Item(val name: String, val type: Type) {}
```